# duplicate session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

using asp.net in c# is there any way for me to check if a session value already exists. Its kind of hard for me to explain but ill try:

User1 logs in - enters a username (jSmith) this value will be the only way of identifying user1. No passwords or database entries will be made. A session variable will be made holding this information
User2 logs in - enters a username (jSmith) as this value already exists I want to be able to stop user2 from setting this value

Thank you!

Comment: You need `if-condition` to check session variable exists or not. For example: `if (Session["UserName"] != null) { //do something } else { //check which user }`

Comment: @HassanNisar, that won't work. Sessions for users are completely independent. As mentioned in Matts answer, he needs to use a common object such as the Application object or store the names in a static object or database.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you. I got it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the session variable is unique to each user.  That is to say that `Session["Foo"]` for user A will be completely different from `Session["Foo"]` for user B.  Also, session variables can go out of scope for various reasons, most commonly memory pressure.  I would hate for your users to get 'logged out' randomly when the server gets busy.

You may want to consider the `Application` object, as its contents are shared across all users.  Also, you may to consider any static object would also be accessible cross requests.  Personally, I would consider storing the data in static collection (hopefully having some sort of thread-safety built in)...

For example:

```
public static class UserHelper 
{
   public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> CurrentUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();
}
```

Then to consume

```
if(UserHelper.CurrentUsers.TryAdd("jSmith", DateTime.Now))
    return "User Login recorded.";
else
    return "User already logged in, try again."
```